# Deming regression implementation: force intercept to 0

Tags: regression, intercept, total-least-squares

I implemented Deming Regression in a known programming language, using the algorithm from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression
However, the algo does not specify what to do in case we want to **force intercept** to 0. I am assuming slope will slightly change as well as R^2 parameter (goodness of fit). Kindly advise on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking to find an answer to the same question but did not manage to find it anywhere. So I tried to derive the answer myself using as a guide the MethComp paper linked to the wikipedia page [Jensen](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/vignettes/Deming.pdf?root=methcomp). The difference to the paper is that we are trying to solve for a following model:
\begin{align} x_i = \xi_i e_{xi} \end{align}
\begin{align} y_i = \beta \xi_i e_{yi} \end{align}
where random part is normally distributed
\begin{align} e_{xi} \sim N(0, \sigma^2) \end{align}
\begin{align} e_{yi} \sim N(0, \lambda \sigma^2) \end{align}

This leads to a slightly easier likelihood function:

\begin{align} f = \prod_{i=1}^n(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} exp(-\frac{(x_i-\xi_i)^2}{2\sigma^2})(2\pi\lambda\sigma^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} exp(-\frac{(y_i-\beta\xi_i)^2}{2\lambda\sigma^2}) \end{align}

The maximum likelihood solution is following:
\begin{align} \beta = \frac{A_{yy}-\lambda A_{xx}+\sqrt{(A_{yy}-\lambda A_{xx})^2 + 4 \lambda A_{xy}^2}}{2A_{xy}}  \end{align}
\begin{align} \xi_{i}=\frac{\lambda x_i + \beta y_i}{\lambda+\beta^2}  \end{align}
where:
\begin{align} A_{xx} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2  \end{align}
\begin{align} A_{yy} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n y_i^2  \end{align}
\begin{align} A_{xy} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n x_i y_i  \end{align}
The whole difference to the original solution with the intercept is lack of correction for averages in definition of $A_{kk}$.